# Sequelize with sqlite dialict on node v5

Tags: node.js, sqlite, ubuntu, sequelize.js

This is my code for example:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

var sequelize = new Sequelize(undefined,undefined, undefined, {
  dialect: 'sqlite',
  // SQLite only
  storage: 'database.db'
});
```

The error is:

```
/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:205
    throw new Error('The dialect ' + this.getDialect() + ' is not supported. S
          ^
Error: The dialect sqlite is not supported. Supported dialects: mariadb, mssql, mysql, postgres, and sqlite. (Error: Please install sqlite3 package manually)
    at new Sequelize (/home/josecarlos/WebstormProjects/sequelize-test/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:205:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/josecarlos/WebstormProjects/sequelize-test/index.js:2:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3

Process finished with exit code 8
```

node version 5

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sequlisze-test",
  "description": "The API server for an ERP.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^3.14.1",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

SO: Kubuntu 15.10 / 4.2.0-19-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 11 11:39:30 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm instaled sqlite: SQLite version 2.8.17.

Thanks you in advances.

Jose Carlos Ramos Carmenates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is node v5 and sqlite3, I solved it:

1- removing node_modules folder.

2- callback to node v0.10.25

```
nvm use system
```

3- verify node version:

```
node -v
```

4- Install sequelize and sqlite

```
npm install --save sequelize sqlite3
```

... ... ...

Comment: Out of interest (and because I've experienced the issue today), is this still the accepted and necessary solution to this problem?